# Handle connection close with python jsocket

Tags: python, sockets

I am using a json socket server/client using the [`jsocket` python library.](https://cpiekarski.com/2012/01/25/python-json-client-server-redux/)

I made request to the server with a client that is open and close the connection each time.
My server crashes after the first time the connection is closed. How can I maintain the server running?

The server code:

```
import logging
import random
import sys
import time

import jsocket

logging.basicConfig(stream=sys.stdout, level=logging.DEBUG)


class DataloggerServer(jsocket.ServerFactoryThread):
    # This is an example factory thread, which the server factory will
    # instantiate for each new connection.
    def __init__(self):
        super(DataloggerServer, self).__init__()
        self.timeout = 2.0

#    def isAlive(self):
#        return True

    def _process_message(self, obj):
        # virtual method - Implementer must define protocol
        logging.debug("Recived object %s", obj)
        if obj != '':
            if obj['type'] == "REQ_VAR_SAMPLE":
                data = obj['data']
                var_name = data["id"]
                logging.debug("Got variable name %s", var_name)
                if var_name == 'EMERGENCY':
                    value = 0 if random.random() < 0.75 else 1
                    logging.debug("variable value: %s", value)
                elif var_name == "RPM_SPINDLE":
                    value = 70 if random.random() < 0.85 else 45
                elif var_name == "FEEDRATE_OVERRIDE":
                    value = 50 if random.random() < 0.85 else 75
                sample = {}
                timestamp = int(time.time()*1000)
                sample['timestamp'] = timestamp
                sample['value'] = value
                logging.debug("created sample %s", sample)
            else:
                logging.info(obj)
                sample = {}
        data = {'sample': sample}
        res_obj = {
                "type": "RESP_SAMPLE",
                "data": data
        }
        logging.debug("Response object: %s", res_obj)
        self.send_obj(res_obj)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    server = jsocket.ServerFactory(DataloggerServer, address="0.0.0.0", port=12340)
    server.timeout = 2.0
    server.start()
    print("Datalogger server started")
```

The client, basically, does this:

```
    monitor_client.open()
    value_timestamp, value = monitor_client.get_var_sample(variable_name)
    monitor_client.close()
```

where `monitor_client` has a  `jsocket.JsonClient` attribute object. Opens connection, does some request and closes the connection. When the client closes I got the following error at the server side:

```
DEBUG:root:Response object: {'type': 'RESP_SAMPLE', 'data': {'sample': {'timestamp': 1630055461803, 'value': 0}}}
  File "/home/zia/.local/share/virtualenvs/vixion-edge-horus-notifier-sNtaDgls/lib/python3.9/site-packages/jsocket/tserver.py", line 162, in run
    self._purge_threads()
  File "/home/zia/.local/share/virtualenvs/vixion-edge-horus-notifier-sNtaDgls/lib/python3.9/site-packages/jsocket/tserver.py", line 189, in _purge_threads
    if not t.isAlive():
AttributeError: 'DataloggerServer' object has no attribute 'isAlive'
INFO:jsocket.tserver:client connection broken, closing socket
DEBUG:jsocket:closing the connection socket
DEBUG:jsocket:closing main socket
```

(The first line is correct debug info).

Answer (score 0):

I added the follwing method to the server:

```
def isAlive(self):
    return self._isAlive
```

But the problem was related to the client. It was clossing the socket before finishing all the requests.